# onInvitationReceived not triggered reliably

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, google-play-services

I looked for help here [listener1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817405/oninvitationreceived-not-being-called) and here [listener2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248402/oninvitationreceivedlistener-does-not-fire-reliably-if-at-all-google-play-ga) and did the same suggestions hoping for a fix, but I still get the function `onInvitationReceived` triggering like only 20% of the time.

Launching the intent to show the invitation inbox however shows that the invitations are there all the time.

Before testing I make sure i don't have pending invites as I think subsequent invites are not triggered.

Any solution for this not involving timer based call to the `getGamesClient().loadInvitations`? (very hacky way to test for invites).

Really `onInvitationReceived` should trigger as a call to `getGamesClient().getInvitationInboxIntent()` shows that there are invites living in there.

Is there something I should do/ not do? or is it a GooglePlay API bug? or what is it? (Hoping for an answer from the GooglePlay devs).

Devices are both Nexus 7, one with Android 4.3 and the other 4.2.2

Comment: I have the same issue... have you solved it?

Comment: Still have the same issue...

Comment: So it's a Google bug? The only way to solve it is to use a timer and call loadInvitations?

Comment: I am thinking to implement the timer/loadinvitation in a background thread if I get the same issue when going through the beta test phase.

Comment: Looks like there is no answer from google, so I don't know if it's a google bug (very likely it is one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New google API doesn't solve this issue. (tested and confirmed).

The best way I found around this unfixed bug (unfix-able by google?) is to use a timer to poll for the invitations using `Games.Invitations.loadInvitations` in addition to listening to `onInvitationReceived`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was infact an issue with Google. That is why [the GamesClient class is now deprecated.](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html)

I have recently started using [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) and the [Games](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games.html) class as suggested by the android developers and I receive invitations reliably now. :)

Comment: I just refactored the code to use the shiny new non-plug and play non compatible google api...and I still don't get invitations reliably, the same as when using the old API.

Comment: Also, using the timer and and polling solution to force get those invitation using Games.Invitations.loadInvitations works, while the onInvitationReceived is waiting forever for father santa.